# Does existence of non-trivial solution of $S(x,y,z) = 0, \; S(y,z,x) = 0, \; S(z,x,y) = 0$ implies existence of trivial solution at $x=y=z$ axis?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, examples-counterexamples

My question is following. Suppose that you have an implicit surface given by equation $S(x,y,z) = 0$ (if it matters, now $S(x,y,z)$ is a polynomial function). I'm interested only in $\mathbb{R}^3_{+}$ part of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (you may think that $S(x,y,z)$ is symmetric under $(x,y,z) \mapsto (\pm x, \pm y, \pm z)$ ). 
In my case the intersection of $S(x,y,z)$ with coordinate planes will look like on the picture:

[image: Scheme of intersection]

Let the cyclic group of 3rd order act on $\mathbb{R}^3$ via cyclic shift $(x,y,z) \mapsto (y,z,x)$.

[image: Example of fundamental domain]

It's easy to see that if $\lbrace S(x,y,z) = 0 \rbrace \cap \mathbb{R}^3_+$ is fully contained in some fundamental domain of group action then system of equations $S(x,y,z) = 0, \; S(y,z,x) = 0 \; S(z,x,y) = 0 $ has no solution. If $S(x,y,z)$ intersects with only one face of fundamental domain, then the same result holds.

Now suppose that we have a non-trivial solution of system $S(x,y,z) = 0, \; S(y,z,x) = 0 \; S(z,x,y) = 0 $. By non-trivial I mean solution that is inner point of group action's fundamental domain. Now the question goes here:

*My hypothesis is that such surface $S(x,y,z)$ necessarily will have intersection with line $x=y=z$. Are there any counterexamples that immediately jump to your mind or is there any proof sketch?*

**UPDATE** So, the most important feature of $S(x,y,z)$ is that $S(x,y,0) = 0$ has solution. Solution set consists of two compact connectivity components (see the picture 1 for example). The same for $S(x,0,z)$ and $S(0,y,z)$

Comment: I have a question. Should I create a new question if I want to clarify some specific details that are in spirit of this question, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following: Consider a torus
$$\bigl(\sqrt{\xi^2+\eta^2}-a\bigr)^2 +\zeta^2=b^2,\qquad 0<b<a,$$
in $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$-coordinates. After a suitable squaring this can be written in the form
$$\Phi(\xi,\eta,\zeta)=0\ ,\tag{1}$$ where $\Phi$ is some polynomial of degree $4$ in the variables $\xi$, $\eta$, $\zeta$.

Then let the $\zeta$-axis point in direction $(1,1,1)$ of $(x,y,z)$-space and choose the $\xi$- and the $\eta$-axis orthogonal in the plane $x+y+z=0$. The greek and the latin variables will then be related by an orthogonal linear transformation. It follows that the torus is given in the latin variables by an equation of the form
$$\Psi(x,y,z)=0\ ,$$
where  $\Psi$ is a symmetric polynomial of degree $4$ in the latin variables. Choosing the parameters $a$ and $b$ appropriately you can make sure that the torus intersects the coordinate planes. But it will not intersect the line $x=y=z$.

If symmetry is important, here is another idea: Consider the edge-skeleton of the octahedron $|x|+|y|+|z|\leq1$ and replace the edges by tubes of radius $r\ll1$ soldered together in a smooth way. The resultant surface has the symmetries you want and does not intersect the line $x=y=z$. Some people will even find a polynomial equation $\Omega(x,y,z)=0$ that defines such a surface.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it! The only thing that confuses me beforehand is that your polynomial might be not invariant under $(x,y,z) \mapsto (\pm x, \pm y, \pm z)$ symmetry. But I haven't stressed this condition before, so maybe it's time to reconsider it's importance.

Comment: The second example is great, thank you a lot! At first I thought it's way too symmetric (and the solution set is infinite; however I haven't stressed the fact that I usually obtain a finite solution set), but it can be easily deformed to non-symmetric surface with the same property. There is only one case left then: your example is a connected surface; however, it's possible for $S(x,y,z)$ to be consisted of two connected components. Will something change in this case?

Answer (score 1):

What about

$$
S(x,y,z)=4-x^2(y^2+z^2)+yz^2(7x-y)
$$

We have $S(1,2,0)=S(2,0,1)=S(0,1,2)=0$ but $S(t,t,t)=4(t^4+1)\neq 0$

Comment: The only problem with you counterexample is that $S(x,y,0) \equiv 72$, while my class of surfaces has intersection with $Oxy$. However, it proves that generally my hypothesis will fail. Anyway, can you explain how this example has been constructed?

Comment: @Evgeny I changed my numerical values taking your comment into account. I found this example by solving the linear system coming from the conditions written above.

Comment: This time it is closer to what I look for. But the intersection is non-compact and has only one connectivity component in $\mathbb{R}^2_+$. Still it's rather vague how formula such as your's could be derived from linear system. I'm curious because system looks so thoughtfully constructed that it can't be (from observer's point of view) just a method of undetermined coefficients :)

Comment: Which intersection is non-compact ?

Comment: From $S(x,y, 0) = 0$ follows that $\vert xy \vert = 2$ on plane $Oxy$. It's a pair of hyperbolae as I see it.